# Get Wrike project structure as nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I want to get the dictionary as a hierarchy of keys, where a key is a folder or task from a Wrike project.
I have a function get_folder(idx) that takes a folder id and returns a dictionary with the keys id, childIds, title. The current title is added to the dictionary hierarchy as the root key.
Then iterates over childIds and gets the next dictionary, whose title must be a child of the root dictionary.
If that dictionary has childIds, then I repeat the iteration.
I have a problem with writing the recursive function correctly.

Wrike project with mixed folder/project/task structure:

```
**MAIN_FOLDER**
--*PRJ01*    
--*PRJ02*   
--*PRJ03*
----PRJ03_SUBFOLDER01
----PRJ03_SUBFOLDER02
```

I want to get this structure as nested dictionary.

My current code:

```
import requests
import json


token = ""
startpoint = 'https://www.wrike.com/api/v4'
root_id = ''


def make_request(endpoint):
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    url = f"{startpoint}/{endpoint}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()

def get_folder(idx):
    data = make_request(f"folders/{idx}")['data'][0]
    filtered_dict = {
                    'title': data['title'],
                    'id': data['id'],
                    'childIds': data['childIds']
                    }
    return filtered_dict


def traverse(folder_id):

    hierarchy = {}

    folder_data = get_folder(folder_id)
    folder_title = folder_data['title']
    folder_id = folder_data['id']
    folder_childIds = folder_data['childIds']

    if folder_title not in hierarchy:
        hierarchy[folder_title] = {}

    if folder_childIds != []:
        for folder_childId in folder_childIds:
            child_data = get_folder(folder_childId)
            child_title = child_data['title']
            child_id = child_data['id']
            child_childIds = child_data['childIds']

            hierarchy[folder_title][child_title] = hierarchy.get(child_title, {})

            traverse(child_id)

    return hierarchy

hierarchy = traverse(root_id)
print(hierarchy)
```

result:
`{'MAIN_FOLDER': {'PRJ01': {}, 'PRJ02': {}}}`

Comment: You need to assign the result of the recursive call somewhere, like a dictionary element.

Comment: Probably something like `hierarchy[folder_title][child_title] = traverse(child_id)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have now encountered the duplicate key bug.   { "TEST_FOLDER": { "PRJ01": { "PRJ01": {}}, "PRJ02": { "PRJ02": {}}, "PRJ03": { "PRJ03": {"PRJ03_SUBFOLDER01": {"PRJ03_SUBFOLDER01": {}}, "PRJ03_SUBFOLDER02": {"PRJ03_SUBFOLDER02": {}}}}}}

Comment: You shouldn't put the folder title into `hierarchy`, since it's in the parent dictionary. So you just want `hierarchy[child_title] =`

Comment: Can you show what the desired result should be? And how does the structure you show at the top relate to `child_id` and `child_name`?

Comment: I want to get this result {"TEST_FOLDER": {}, "PRJ01": {}, "PRJ02": {}, "PRJ03": {"PRJ03_SUBFOLDER01": {},"PRJ03_SUBFOLDER02": {}}}

Comment: MAIN FOLDER is the title from the dictionary obtained from the first return get_folder(folder_id), PRJ01 PRJ02 PRJ03 are the titles whose id's were childIds from the first return. PRJ03_SUBFOLDER01 PRJ03_SUBFOLDER02 are the titles whose id's were childIds for the iteration that returned the dictionary with title PRJ03

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add 2 levels of dictionary in `traverse()`. Each traversal just adds 1 level to the nested dictionaries. You're getting duplicate keys because you assign the key in the caller (when it's `child_title`) and callee (when it's `folder_title`).

When you make the recursive call, assign the result to the dictionary element for that child title.

```
def traverse(folder_id):
    hierarchy = {}

    folder_data = get_folder(folder_id)
    folder_childIds = folder_data['childIds']

    for folder_childId in folder_childIds:
        child_data = get_folder(folder_childId)
        child_title = child_data['title']
        child_id = child_data['id']

        hierarchy[child_title] = traverse(child_id)

    return hierarchy
```

There's no need for `if folder_childIds != []:`. If the list is empty, the loop won't do anything.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the solution and tips, they helped me a lot.  Recursive functions are a challenge for me. There is still a lot to work on.